# How to programatically navigate to the last or n-th page of antd table component?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, antd

I am adding a new item to antd table component with pagination component and would like to navigate table contents to last or n-th page in pagination. How can I programatically navigate to the last or n-th page of antd table component with antd pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

1) Add pagination object to component state

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state =
            {
                pagination: null,
            };
    }
```

2) Pass pagination from component state to Tables pagination prop in your components render method:

```
    ...
    <Table
        dataSource={dataSource}
        ...
        pagination={this.state.pagination}
    />
    ...
```

3) In your components event handler of your choice you can now use SetState to set pagination object. For example I navigate to the last page in pagination after new item is added to the table:

```
handleCreateItem = () => {
        ...
        let pagination = {
            current: YourNewCurrentPageInPagination,
            maxSize: YourNewMaxSizeGridValue
        }
        ...
        this.setState({
            pagination: pagination
        })
        ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, Im on the same issue. How did u calculate YourNewCurrentPageInPagination??

Answer (score 0):

You can control it by `Table[pagination]`, see: https://ant.design/components/table/#Table